# what is the right approach for Bundling and minification js and css files in .net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

For bundling and minification of js and css files, does it have to be done on a page by page basis i.e. bundle all the js that page uses into one js and css file, or bundle into one single js and css for the entire website?

Comment: Its usually not 1 for all or 100 each for one page, but around 2-3 different bundles for all your pages. You have a basic library, like jQuery that you load alone, and then 2-3 main bundle libraries that you use on 2-3 different works. For example 10-20 pages can use almost the same set of javascript files.

Comment: Thank you! But window.load in every js file gets executed no matter which page we are in...

Comment: Minification and bundles are done to achive the goal to reduce band with usage, size response and speed up server with low http reqeust.So the best think that you can do is to make the stuff more simple possibile and find the right solution that you can. You can create more bunlde as you need and use it in a page.Personally i create a placeholder at bottom page or in the head of the page(as per my need) which i use only for bundle and minification and i load only what i need.It is a more simple and flexible way to have full controll of it.The same for css too